# How can we improve the timezone tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Working with coworkers, vendors or customers from other timezone(s) is a unique challenge that requires a separate set of skills to navigate properly. It would be helpful to tag questions where the multiple timezone setting is an important factor to consider. I have started off with creating a [timezone](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timezone) tag, but I think it doesn't describe the scenario entirely.

I would like to hear what the community has to say about it. Do we need such a tag? If yes, can we identify a better name and/or excerpt? Or are we ok with the current name and excerpt?

Comment: No need for this. We already have far too many tags, IMHO.

Comment: Can you link some questions where you think the tag would be useful? So far there's only the one, and the OP specifically said that time zone isn't an issue (though answers do disagree). I would think any timezone questions would be encompassed by the [tag:scheduling] tag.

Comment: @David Yes, I do have a few questions in mind. Will post links when I am back to a desktop (searching and posting links is hard on mobile). I can see what you mean about the scheduling, there is certainly significant overlap between the two. But certain timezone problems are not solvable by better scheduling alone, in particular asynchronous communication like email and impromptu meetings, which are often a business need. Those two tags are certainly closely related but cover different concepts IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend changing it to

[time-difference](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-difference)

> For questions of issues relating to dealing with differences in time zones or the difficulties created by communicating/scheduling over time-zones